# How to toggle submenu with EventListener only javascript without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to javacript, I'm trying to code about toggling submenu with EventListener. My subtopics is hiding when users click at Topics i want subtopics element shows up and hide itself again when users click at Topics or click anywhere in webpages.

I have searched about this topics, mostly people are using classList because it's the most supporting browsers. But When i run code it didn't work for me. and i tried to figure it out but i really can't.

I'm very poor experience and also doing my best, so i need help from people. If someone would like to give me some advices i would appreciate it thank you.

Here is my code please take a look.

```js
var subTopics = document.getElementById("subtopics");

subTopics.addEventListener("click", function () {
    subTopics.classList.add("show");
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Topics</a>
                <div id="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are assigning click event to 'subtopics' here.  var subTopics = document.getElementById("subtopics");  But 'subtopic' is hidden by default . Set click listner on li 'Topics' and try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You added a click event to a hidden element (`#subtopics`), and one can't click on a hidden one.

Here is a suggestion to show how you could do, where I added a class to the `li`, and toggle the `show` class on it.

*See notes in the sample 1's CSS and script*

Sample 1

```js
var subTopics = document.querySelector(".subtopics");  // target the li

subTopics.addEventListener("click", function (e) {     // passed "e" to get the event
    e.preventDefault();                                // prevent anchor to navigate
    subTopics.classList.toggle("show");                // changed to toggle for the
                                                       // the purpose of this demo
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.subtopics.show #subtopics {             /*  changed  */
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="subtopics"><a href="#">Topics</a>
                <div id="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Sample 2

A more generic approach could look like this

```js
var submenus = document.querySelectorAll(".hassubmenu");

for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
  submenus[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var last = this.closest('ul').querySelector('.show');
    if (last && last !== this) last.classList.remove("show");
    this.classList.toggle("show");
  });
}

// added based on a comment, this will also hide any menu when clicked anywhere else
document.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var last = document.querySelector('#mainmenu .show');
  if (last) last.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.hassubmenu.show .submenu {             /*  changed  */
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.submenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.submenu li {
    display: block;
}

.submenu a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hassubmenu"><a href="#">Topics</a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="hassubmenu"><a href="#">Services</a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <div id="column2" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the best solution for my case, i also hope that this answer can help other people thank you @LGSon

Comment: @Saranyuquestion Thanks...and I also added a 2nd sample, a generic approach, to handle more than one sub menu.

Comment: I would like to ask you one more question please. In CSS file at .subtopics.show when i press space bar between .subtopcs and .show(.subtopcs..show) to be .subtopcs .show why it isn't working ? Is there any rule about it ?

Comment: @Saranyuquestion Yes, when an element has multiple classes (even if combined with an `id` selector), they need to be chained in the CSS, or else it become a descendant selector, e.g. `.subtopics .show` would mean _"target an element with class `show` that has an ancestor with class `subtopics`"_

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you again, actually the real function that i want aside from by clicking submenu and hide by itself, i also want submenu  hide by clicking anywhere in webpage as well.Can you help me about this please ?

Comment: @Saranyuquestion I added a solution to that in my 2nd sample

Comment: @LGSon Sorry man, I realized how silly and petty I sounded and decided to just drop the whole thing in shame. I like this answer, keep it up!

Comment: @ippi Thanks, and no shame in speaking up for yourself :), though I would have kept it with the 3rd point, as it is a valid and good point. I did an update of your answer, either revert it back or undelete. If you undelete it, let me know and I'll give it an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jQuery:

```js
$('#mainmenu a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var subtopic = $(this).parent().find('.subtopics');
  $('.subtopics').not(subtopic).hide();
  subtopic.show();
})
$(document).click(function(event){
  $('.subtopics').hide();
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
.subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

3subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

3subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Logo</a>
                <div class="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Topics</a>
                <div class="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm only learning javascript may you help me out about javascript please ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function toggle() {
var subTopics = document.getElementById("subtopics");
if (subTopics.className === "show") {
  subTopics.className = "hidden";
} else {
  subTopics.className = "show";
}

  }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#mainmenu {
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#subtopics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#subtopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subtopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#mainmenu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onClick="toggle()">Topics</a>
                <div id="subtopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one's working for me, can you run the snippet and confirm if this is what you want.

Comment: I also want submenu hide when users click anywhere in webpage as well.Canyou provide me some code please?